mark minor-mode
I'm searching for a minor mode that will let me mark positions and region coordinates to eventually generate a buffer of sed or awk script.
Is there already something that exist to do such a way of working with text documents, info mode, man mode, etc.
Preferably triggered by only one sequence of keystrokes.

Just what do you mean by "mark positions and region coordinates"? Interactively (you speak of keystrokes)? Are you just trying to get buffer positions using Elisp code? The question isn't very clear.

Why a minor mode specifically?  And how are you moving between the positions if marking all of the positions is "one sequence of keystrokes"?  (Unless you only want to identify positions which are currently visible, in which case a UI like avy would facilitate that).

The term 'mark', that I have in head while writing this question, is maybe misleading. It may be a keystroke that will send the file line number (for a position) or a range of line number (for a region), to an other buffer. This is while I read a document file. Latter, when needed, I may convert the buffer coordinate to a sed or awk script for doing things in shell.

I have read about avy and it's not what I'm looking for. The method I'm searching is; while I read a document in an emacs buffer, I use a keystroke to record coordinate, somewhere.
